# Where do webpack assets go in an Angular 2 CLI project

Tags: angular, assets, angular-cli

Where should I place general, cross-component `.css`, `.scss`, `.svg`, `.gif`, etc. assets (e.g., theme resources) in an Angular CLI (webpack) project so both the development and production versions of my application work correctly without changes?

When I generate a new `foo` project with [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io) (`angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8, node: 6.5.0, os: linux x64`) using `ng new foo --styles=scss`, the following structure is created (with `node_modules` trimmed):

```
foo
├── angular-cli.json
├── config
│   ├── karma.conf.js
│   └── protractor.conf.js
├── e2e
│   ├── app.e2e-spec.ts
│   ├── app.po.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── public
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.component.css
│   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   ├── app.module.ts
│   │   ├── environments
│   │   │   ├── environment.dev.ts
│   │   │   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   │   │   └── environment.ts
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   └── shared
│   │       └── index.ts
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── polyfills.ts
│   ├── test.ts
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── typings.d.ts
└── tslint.json
```

The `public` area seems reasonable but what about `.scss` files? The `src/app/public` seems reasonable as well, but what the right directory to allow the development and production versions to work correctly?

What should file references look like in HTML and SCSS files? Are they all relative paths based on source layout in SCSS files (e.g.`@import '../scss/layout';`) and absolute paths in HTML files (e.g., `<link href="/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you migrated an existing project, make a styles.scss under `src/`, that file is meant for global styles. You can also put them under `app.component.scss`

Comment: Thanks, @Robert -- how do I handle a set of `.scss` "global" style files?

Comment: I would use import statements inside the styles.scss file.

`@import '/path/to/file.scss';`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but instead of making one huge .scss file, compiling it and linking it to index.html, I would recommend using the angular cli scss support.

First you need to install node-sass by doing `npm install node-sass --save-dev`

Then your component should look like this

```
@Component({
templateUrl: 'file.html',
directives: [your-directives],
styleUrls: ['path/to/file.scss'] // (or just ['file.scss'] in the same directory
```

when you `ng serve` or `ng build` or whatever it just automatically compiles the scss files.

Of course change your `app.component.css` to `app.component.scss`. No need to use compass or any other scss compiler. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @Abu Barrett -- what about more general resources like theme definitions, etc. which span components? I'll update my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Right now angular-cli is quite unfinished, untill the webpack.2 version, the public folder worked to serve global files (in the near future I'm sure they'll fix it) . and yes, some times you need global scss assets. If you're talking about scss you could just import a global scss to your specific component scss files. for example inside the app folder you could create a "styles" folder and have a _shared.scss file and import it in component scss file like this: @import '../styles/shared';